# NA replacement using mean or median value? Any other alternative methods?

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation, methodology

I have the following dataset:

```
5   3   3   5   10  10  3   8   2   12  8   6   2   5   6   5   10  4   3   5   4   3   3   5   8   3   5   6   6   1   10  3   6   6   5   8   3   4   3   4   4   3   2.5 1   4   2   2   3   5   10  4   4   6   3   2   3   8   3   4   4   3   3   4   8   4   4   2   4   4   3   2   10  6   3   7   3   5   3   1   4   3   4   3   4   4   2   3   2   4   7   4   6   3.5 3.5 5   3   4   3   5   3   1.5 2.5 3   7   2   5   3   4   2   4   5   3   4   5   4.5 4   6   3   2   1   3   2   2   3   4   6   2   4   2   3   6   1.5 3   3   1   4   3   3   2   3   2   2   6   3   15  1   4   5   2   6   2   4   8   2   8   4   4   4   3   8   4   4   8.5 3   2   7   0.5 3   3   3   2   3   2   4   5   6   2   3.5 3   3   2   2   2.5 2   2   5   2   8   2   4   3   3   2   7   2   4   2   4   4   3   2.5 3   3   3   5 NA NA NA NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I want to replace NA's using either **Mean or Median value imputation method**.

Which method would be appropriate in such a case, and why?

Please help me learning.

Thanks.

In R I am trying the same with Median using:

```
# replacing with Median
df$val[is.na(df$val)] <- with(df, 
                                  ave(val, FUN = function(x) 
                                            median(x, na.rm = TRUE)) [is.na(df$val)]
```

**I have a feeling that this is not correct way of imputation.**

Can someone help in clarifying my doubts:

1. Will there be any effects on median imputation, given that there are some values with high frequencies and others with low freq.
2. Because of outliers, imputation with "mean" would not be a good idea. So what alternative methods could be there?

Thanks.

Comment: Although I'd love to answer this question again, I'd rather refer you here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257672/can-i-replace-nas-based-on-response-variable/257680#257680